# How to convert an `Arc<dyn SubTrait>` into an `Arc<dyn SuperTrait >`?

Tags: rust, traits, dynamic-dispatch, trait-objects

I have a library that needs things to implement a specific trait (`TQDispatch`).

In my main project I have a vector of objects that all implement a different trait (`Device`) which I need for dynamic dispatch.

The device trait is declared

```
pub trait Device: TQDispatch{..}
```

My expectation is that I can take an item from the list of `Device` implementers and get at its `TQDispatch`-ness so that I can pass it to the library. Given that anything that implements `Device` also implements `TQDispatch`, this seems like it should be possible.

I can cast the original 'real' object to either, but I cannot find how to cast between the two traits.

Clarification: These are `Arc<dyn Device>` in my project vector and I need them to be `Arc<dyn TQDispatch>` for the library.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at [this](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/casting-traitobject-to-super-trait/33524)

Comment: [Here a simple sample](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f0f4e9c85bbdf7089a00530e6dc03cff)

Comment: [The top answer to the other question applied here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=88e561769deb807e054420768439794e). You can do a little better on nightly with [specialization](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9a2c31b7a5dd05e1f943ebd61e87f146). It's not impossible that [built-in supertrait coercions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/60900) will be implemented in the future, but I wouldn't personally hold my breath for it.

Comment: @trentcl can you get something to work with `min_specialization`? The full `specialization` feature is unlikely to be stable any time soon.

Comment: @PeterHall Hmm... I don't really understand `min_specialization`. For that matter, I don't really understand `specialization`, either -- I thought the `default` was required but I guess it isn't? [Removing `default` and changing the feature name seems to work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c396a0434f283d3fc97cf1fd3cff2d7c), but only when the upcasting method is the only thing in the trait (which probably makes this not very useful).

Answer (score 1):

> I can cast the original 'real' object to either, but I cannot find how to cast between the 2 traits.

You need to implement an explicit conversion in the "sub-trait".

Rust is not an inheritance-based language, so

```rust
pub trait Device: TQDispatch{..}
```

means "Device *requires* TQDispatch", not "Device *extends* TQDispatch".

If you want an `Arc` output, you will also need to create a brand new Arc for that, because `dyn Device` and `dyn TQDispatch` are different values entirely.